# After many successive and successful queries SQL Server starts refusing connections

Tags: sql-server, docker, node.js

I have a GraphQL server ( Node v14.15.1 ) which uses typeorm to connect to a SQL Server 12.0.4100.1, also it runs inside a docker container, connection parameters are:

```javascript
  let connection = await createConnection({
    type: "mssql",
    host: HOST,
    port: PORT,
    database: DB,
    username: USER,
    password: PASSWORD,
    // NOTE: Use typeorm-model-generator for Entities
    logging: false,
    synchronize: true,
    requestTimeout: 300000,
    connectionTimeout: 300000,
    entities: ["./models/mssql"],
    pool: {
      max: 1000, min: 1,
      idleTimeoutMillis: 3000,
      evictionRunIntervalMillis: 1500000,
    },
    options: {
      encrypt: false,
    }
  })
```

**Problem:**
After numerous sucessful queries the SQL Server starts refusing connections with the error:

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to adress: port - connect ECONNREFUSED adress: port\n
    at ConnectionError (/home/raa/code/wcc-gql/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js: 13: 12)\n
    at Connection.socketError (/home/raa/code/wcc-gql/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js: 1290: 56)\n
    at _connector.Connector.execute (/home/raa/code/wcc-gql/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js: 1116: 21)\n
    at Socket.onError (/home/raa/code/wcc-gql/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connector.js: 140: 7)\n
    at Socket.emit (events.js: 198: 13)\n
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js: 91: 8)\n
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js: 59: 3)\n
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js: 63: 19)'
```

The problem happens when query a specific type which looking down the hierarchy has a lot of resolvers, also the amount of data varies.
The more data the more likely that the problem will occur.
What also interesting is that it is more likely that the problem will occur if the program is running inside a container or as PM2 service.

I've tested the same data where connections are refused inside a container and not refused in VS Code debugger or when run from terminal.
I tried fiddling with the pool options which gave modest results.
I've also checked that I do not exceed the amount of connections allowed by the DB.
I've checked the logs on the SQL Server, there are no issues or errors in them at the time I make requests. I've just now added support for tracking log attempts on the SQL Server and it now registers some 776 successful logins from this application in period 15:03:46.01 - 15:04:48.07 and after that I assume the I get the errors.

### EDIT:

I've tried changing the Network Packet Size option in Sql Server options and packetSize connection options of typeorm -> mssql -> tedious which didn't work but revealed some new details. Since I had to reset the server apply new Sql Options, immediately after the reset the queries successfully finished.

So I tried tracking the resources and saw that the server ramps up to 100% processor capacity pretty quickly and after that has problems opening new connections and if I allow a too large max in pool options (in my case 500) of connections it start refusing connections.

When I bring down the max property, however, a new type of error arises which manifests as `connection timed out from unknown reason` this time stemming from `tarn.js`.

What I think is happening is that the tarm.js(underlying connection pool) has a default timeout for createTimeoutMillis/ adding new connections to pool, and this option is not revealed through the typeorm API and while it waits on the server to unfreeze and allow a new connection to be allotted it times out.

Comment: Hey i've added some more info in the edit section...

Comment: I'm currently debugging in VS Code and the same problem appears, it just takes much less data/connections for the docker version to fail.

Comment: I'll check out this troubleshooting guide, but it seems it not just to the application, there are problems server side also...

Comment: Added version to description

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you had mssql in docker as well. This does seem more like an application error, especially if the mssql logs are clean. You might have better luck on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

What `node.js` version are you on?

Apparently [node version: v.12.6.0 required me to use packetSize: 8192 to avoid the Connection lost - read ECONNRESET error](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/923)

If that is no the problem try to change the Network Packet size in the SSMS Properties

[image]

If you said that the connections mostly works but fails for different data is because of the size of the stream of data.

Comment: Hey, so I tried what you suggested and It didn't work but when I reset the server after an initial few tests it stopped working, so I'm thinking it has to do with resources.

Comment: Oh, that is a nice catch, check the Cost Threshold for Parallelism and MAXDOP https://vroomperformance.com/cost-threshold-for-parallelism-and-maxdop/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, I just want to share the way I solved it since this solution did not help me. I found some obscure timeout settings under "pool" which I increased to a ridiculous amount. I am not sure which one of these helped, but this solved my problem:

```
      const timeout = 120_000_000;

      const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
        user: env.DB_USERNAME,
        password: env.DB_PASSWORD,
        server: env.DB_HOST,
        database: env.DB_DATABASE_NAME,
        options: { trustServerCertificate: true },
        requestTimeout: timeout,
        pool: {
          max: 1000, min: 1,
          idleTimeoutMillis: timeout,
          acquireTimeoutMillis: timeout,
          createTimeoutMillis: timeout,
          destroyTimeoutMillis: timeout,
          reapIntervalMillis: timeout,
          createRetryIntervalMillis: timeout,
        }
      });
```